# Facebook like button press does not stay liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm working on a site for a client.  The site is built in Joomla and is using a Facebook like button on each page.  When a user clicks a like button it unclicks itself after a second or two.

I've seen several similar problems here but none have provided enough insight to help me figure out what to do to fix this problem.

I ran the page through the Facebook debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theartoflove.net%2Findex.php%2F9-blog%2Fmen%2F27-go-ahead-and-ask-her-out

but I don't have a clue how to figure out what that result is telling me.  The URL I used as a test in the debugger is:

http://www.theartoflove.net/index.php/9-blog/men/27-go-ahead-and-ask-her-out

Anyone know what I need to do to fix this problem?  It seems to happen regardless of what like box I put on the site (I've tried three different ones so far).

My sincere thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked the like button, **a small 'CONFIRM' link appeared under the "Like" widget**, i had to click the 'CONFIRM' link (which brought up a dialog box asking me to confirm that I liked the page) in order to get the "Like" to stick.

[See image](http://www.dropbox.com/s/h5djvgz9phogm9r/shot_140118_094842.png)

Facebook sometimes makes the arbitrary determination that your page is 'spammy' and adds extra precautions like 'CONFIRM'. That may be part of what is going on.

Comment: Also noticed you are using **Share It** and NOT using the standard Facebook "Like" widget. Have you tried using the standard/official Facebook widget, since the problem may be with Share It.

Answer (score 0):

The code is reentrant and the developer is flipping the bit instead of verifying the current state with a conditional before setting the value. (This is a common coding mistake. Too common.)